# How to test the child class for equality in Java?

Tags: java, equals, comparator

I am working on a project, but I got stuck in some issue. I need to test equality of child class (DiscountProduct). 
Relation between classes can be understood as: Order class has-a Product and Product is parent of DiscountProduct. I want to test DiscountProduct for equality. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!
Below is the code:

**Order Class:**

```
public class Order implements Comparable<Order>{

    private int quantity;
    //composition has-a relationship
    private Product product;

    public Order(int quantity, Product product) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Order) {
            return product.equals(obj) && quantity == ((Order) obj).quantity;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
}
```

**Product class**

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {

    private String productCode;
    private String description;
    private int unitPrice; //pence

    public Product(String productCode, String description, int unitPrice) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.description = description;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    //equals method to test product for equality.
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (this == obj){
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Product)){
            System.out.println("-");

            return false;
        }
        Order other = (Order) obj;
        if (!productCode.equals(other.getProduct().getProductCode()))
            return false;
        if (!description.equals(other.getProduct().getDescription()))
            return false;        
        if (unitPrice != (other.getProduct().getUnitPrice()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**DiscountProduct class**

```
public class DiscountProduct extends Product {

    private double discountRate;

    public DiscountProduct(String productCode, String description, int unitPrice, double discountRate) {
        super(productCode, description, unitPrice);
        this.discountRate = discountRate;
    }

    //equals method to test discount product for equality.
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        Order other = (Order) obj;
       //how to test for the equality for the discountProduct's field discountRate?
       //does I need to add some method in Order class to get the discountRate of object of Order class, 
       //because relation is 'Order has Product' and then there is a parent-child relation
       //between product and DiscountProduct class. 

    }
}
```

Comment: "*`product.equals(obj)`*" (in `Order::equals`) - This should most probably be `product.equals(obj.product)`. Otherwise, you compare an `Order` with a `Product`, which obviously returns `false`. As an aside: you should also override [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) to satisfy the contract between `equals(...)` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. product.equals(obj.product) sort out the problem. You are a savior man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DiscountProduct` could do something like:

```
@Override // always always always use that annotation when overriding!
public boolean equals(Object obj){
  .. this == obj test
  if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof DiscountProduct)){
    return false;
  } 
  if (super.equals(obj)) {
    cast to DiscountProduct and check discountRate
```

The point here is:

- you really *only* want objects to be equal that are of the same class. Otherwise there is a high chance that you get the necessary `if a.equals(b) then b.equals(a)` rule wrong
- then you want to re-use the existing implementation of the parent class
- to then finally, compare the child class field(s)

It *might* also make sense to declare that "last" version of `equals()` to be `final`, but that really depends on context.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This also helps me to get the desired output. Much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to set the method `final`. otherwise, the [contract of `equals(...)` could be violated (the symmetry, to be exact)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @Turing85 Well, given the fact that the OP is already using one level of inheritance, that might or might not be a good idea. But I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In this part of the code:

```
public class Order implements Comparable<Order>{
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Order) {
            return product.equals(obj) && ...;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

A `Product` is comared with an `Order`. This comparison should obviously return `false` since a `Product` is no `Order`. What you probably meant to write was:

### return product.equals(obj.product) && ...;

A remark on your code: There is a [contract between `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> The general contract of `hashCode` is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in `equals` comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

To conform with this contract, one should always override `hashCode()` when one overridest `equals(...)`.

I would also encourage you to set methods `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` `final`. Otherwise, the [contract of `equals(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) could be violated.